# How to add hair particle to ocean modifier?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, hair

I'm trying to add hair particles system to ocean (so hair will move with the ocean movement) but I realized that I need to bake the ocean before doing that. Can somebody have some tip how to do this?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Why baking animation of Ocean modifier is necessary? Simple add Particle System modifier below the Ocean one in stack and enable Use Modiifer stack in particle system options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the particle system down the modifier stack, so that it comes after the ocean modifier.

(Use the Triangle icons to the right of the modifier to re-arrange the order)

[image]

Then, on the particle system settings enable **Use Modifier Stack**

[image]

From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/hair/emission.html?highlight=use%20modifier%20stack):

> **Use Modifier Stack**
>
> Take any Modifiers above the Particle Modifier in the modifier stack into account when emitting particles.